# How to fix 'Redis server error: socket error on read socket' error in mediawiki

Tags: sockets, redis, mediawiki

I am receiving error as

> Redis server error: socket error on read socket
>   Error received as 'JobQueueError from line xxx of JobQueueRedis.php: Redis server error: socket error on read socket'

I tried by changing persistent connection option to true.

```
$wgObjectCaches['redis'] = [
  'class'       => 'RedisBagOStuff',
  'servers'     => [ $redisserver ],
  'persistent'  => true
];
```

Comment: I tried to check whether redis server is running and is reachable or not using ping(); function. And I can see its returning +PONG. but stil receiving read socket error.

Answer (score 1):

In our case the following errors would occur because our AWS ElasticeCache Redis Cluster was using 100% of available memory :

`"RedisException","message":"socket error on read socket","code":0`
`"RedisClusterException","message":"Error processing response from Redis node!"`

Increasing the number of nodes and or allowing more memory on the instance seemed to solve the problem. But it seems our cached values take a lot of memory and need to expire faster.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was an error in the health check script, which was written with parm `--no-auth-warning`, which was not working for `redis version 4` which caused `redis-cli --no-auth-warning -a password ping` resulted in an error after that, the script was retreating the redis server and server has socket error.